# Member variables vs. State Varaibels? Are they the same?

Tags: design, object-oriented, variables

I am learning that member variables are to hold the state of an object? Is it their recommended usage? Are all member variables state variables too? or state variables have specific definition and  are defined according to a class? In general what is the definition of an state variable?

In fact, I look for the best usage of member variables and how to avoid declaring unnecessary variables and using alternative approaches for example passing parameters to the methods of a class. As I think too many state variables may bring complexity to the state of class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to give good advice on such a broad topic. The honest answer is: it depends on what you want to accomplish.

1) Member variables could represent state of an object. This might or might not be, what you intended to do. If your object lives in a web- / concurrency-context, then that is most of the time not, what you want. In these contexts, most of the time you want *statelessness* / *immutability*. If an object is shared and reads and writes are permitted, there is trouble. Of course there are ways to avoid such problems (e.g. locks etc.) but it is not a good idea to have *mutable* objects.

2) Another usecase for member variables is to hold *dependencies* for the object: e.g. dependencies to repositories, services, etc. These are most of the time injected *once*; sometimes via *constructor-injection* or via *setter-injection*. It would make no sense to avoid using membervariables for these dependencies; on the other hand you would have to inject needed dependencies with each function call. This pollutes the method signature unnecessary and makes using your api complicated.

3) And there is the space in between. If an object is not shared and the membervariable does not represent a dependency you are free to do, what you like. It is wrong to think of them as *global variables* since they are not global - they are limited to the object. And one pillar of object oriented design is *encapsulation* or *information hiding*. It's like dancing naked in your living room: as long as nobody sees it - who cares?

Answer (score 3):

A member variable is any variable that is *scoped to the class.*  That means that any code *within the class* can access the variable. How the variable is used or how it is accessed doesn't matter, with respect to it's *member* status.  Member variables and class/object state are the same thing.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
   // Not a member variable; never changes.
   private const pi = 3.14159;

   // class state; member variable, but shared with all object instances. 
   private static object locker;

   // member variable.
   private List<double> list;

   // member variable.
   private int counter;

   // member variable, but properties are preferred.
   public bool IsSingleton; 

   // not a member variable; part of the class's external API.
   public int Counter
   {
       get { return counter; }
   }

   public double CalculateAverage
   {
       // not a member variable; scoped to method.
       double sum;

       for (int i=0; i< list.Length; i++)
       {
           sum += list[i];
       }
       return sum / list.Length;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know a member variable is a private variable in a class, but I asked should they be restricted to state variables? and what is actually state variable, it seems you say I can declare arbitrary variables and all are counted state variables? then doesn't it bring complexity to the state of class?

Comment: @Ahmad Classes (and functions) should be as small as possible (but no smaller). Your classes should do one thing and should have only the private variables they need to get that job done.

Comment: @Doval Thank you, then it seems I should declare a lot of classes instead of a lot of variables? for anything that I think could be cohesive and well defined?

Comment: @Ahmad: You're overthinking this.  Member variables and state variables are the same thing, so asking if member variables should be restricted to state variables makes no sense.

Comment: @Ahmad Yes. As a rule of thumb, if you have variables that are irrelevant to many of the methods of your class, it's a sign that it (and probably those methods) doesn't belong in there. If your class spans many screens, that's another potential sign that it's doing too much. See [Cohesion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 1):

**One use** of *"declaring variables as members"* is for **attributes**. Them being things that describe the thing you are modeling that, maybe, some external consumer would want to ask. For example the name and age of a person are examples of attributes. These atributes are usually modified using a setter method and read using a getter method.

Attributes are part of the "state" of an object. But other variables besides the attributes are part of the state also.

**The second possible use** is for those kinds of variables. Such variables contain information that are usually read from and written to by several of the class method.

Examples:

- an internal counter ( not the counters in for loops )
- an open database connection
- a list of processed items
- a flag indicating the object is in certain state (waiting, closed, open, available, etc.)

These variables are candidates to be member variables even when no one outside the class need to know them.

What you say about just passing everything as parameters to the methods indicates that such methods are not cohesive to the class and that they should be static.

Maybe you are not modelling real world concepts in a OO way and you are just using classes as applications, i.e, the application is the class, and that's why you don't find it natural to declare member variables.

**One additional tip** is that if you find you are constantly passing the same parameter between several methods, chances are that method should be a member.

**Recomendation:**

Use classes to model real life entities, like BankAccount, Player, Chessman, etc. Don't make a giant class with a giant main method and a lot of helper functions.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed good examples of the usage of member variables. However I thought properties definition is distinct from member variables.

Comment: @Ahmad Attributes are member variables nonetheless.

Comment: I would be cautious about using the word "attributes."  Attributes is a general word, and its meaning in some languages is *not* state.